# ORM for Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I' using pymongo in a project as mongodb interface in python. Is there any way to define structured classes as models and pass them as objects to pymongo. As a matter of fact I mean something like an ORM engine that perform some extra works like model validation and ...

Comment: Couldn't you use google? First link was: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tools.html

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev I blieve Google search is actually blocked in Iran, so not much point

Comment: @Sammaye maybe not: http://www.blockediniran.com/?siteurl=www.google.com

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev Must have unblocked it then however that site also says youtube.com isn't blocked of which I am really skeptical about...especially after why it was blocked. However...